# SSRS: display a message conditionally if the report is empty

Tags: sql, reporting-services

One of my clients is concerned that a report that is returned with **no** records might confuse the user. She would like to have a message at the bottom of the report stating NO DATA if the report is empty.

How could I add a conditional message to the bottom of the SSRS report?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a 'NoRowsMessage' property for tablix. You can set this property to show a custom message when no row is returned.

```
NORowsMessage="No data available for current filter selection"
```

You can also set font size etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add a message to your report with a visibity condition based on the Count of records in your dataset being 0. It should be pretty easy to find using the function button.